# Chrome Extension: 'Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist' error when sending message from popup to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I am developing a Chrome extension that aims to extract the HTML code of the current webpage and display it in a popup window. However, I am facing the following error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." The error occurs when I click a button in the popup to trigger the extraction process.

Key Code Snippets:

Popup Script (popup.js):

```
document.getElementById("extractButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "extractHTML" });
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "htmlExtracted") {
    const extractedHTML = request.html;
    document.getElementById("htmlDisplay").value = extractedHTML;
  }
});
```

Content Script (content.js):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "extractHTML") {
    const html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    chrome.storage.local.set({ extractedHTML: html }, function() {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "htmlExtracted", html: html });
    });
  }
});
```

Additional Notes:

The extension includes necessary permissions in manifest.json, such as "activeTab" and "storage".
The content.js script is correctly injected into all URLs, as specified in the "content_scripts" section of manifest.json.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on resolving this issue. Thank you!

Steps to Reproduce:

Load the extension using "Load unpacked" in chrome://extensions/.
Click on the extension icon to open the popup.
Click on the "Extract HTML" button in the popup.
Expected Behavior:
Upon clicking the "Extract HTML" button, the extension should successfully send a message to the content script, extract the HTML of the current page, and display it in the popup window.

Actual Behavior:
Instead, the extension encounters the "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" error, preventing successful communication between the popup and content scripts.

Comment: Chrome doesn't auto-inject content scripts after installation/update. Instead of messaging and `content_scripts` use executeScript as shown [here](/a/67227376).